# Spring Database backed authentication + Jersey client

Tags: authentication, spring-security, jersey

I want to implement spring database backed authentication for all jersey Client requests.
i have added the spring security filter chain to my web.xml, and this to my spring security context xml file :

```
    <authentication-manager>
          <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myDetailsService">
                  <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" />
          </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
    <beans:bean id="myDetailsService" class="myPackage.MyDetailsService"/>
```

My question is on the MyUserDetailsService class where i want to retrieve user whose credentials (saved in a database) match those sent by the jersey client. this is my impl:

```
class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{
      public MyUserDetailsService(String username,String password){}

     // i get the connexion from datasource
     // and request user with corresponding username/password 
     // and return that user.  
}
```

How can i pass the username/password that i got from jersey client request to create a user? (sent in header or in query URL)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the AuthenticationUserDetailsService class? The Authentication object passed to loadUserDetails has the principal identity and credentials of the user.